# A square with entries whose adjacencies never repeat

Tags: co.combinatorics

Suppose we have an $n \times n$ square, and an alphabet $\Gamma$.  We put an element of $\Gamma$ in each location of the square. An element can appear in more than one location.  The constraint is that a pair $a,b$ of neighbors (either east-west of each other, or north-south of each other) can only appear in that configuration once.

Example of a prohibited square:

a b c
d e f
g d e

Since "de" appears on both the second and the third row, the entries of the square are not acceptable. The same problem would arise if, say, a appeared above d anywhere except the top left corner.

> Given $n$, the width of the square as a parameter, what is a lower bound on the size of the alphabet $\Gamma$?

I would love (suggestions toward) a direct proof, but also, has this type of square-filling problem been studied?  I can't connect it to either a Latin square, or a block design.  Does this map onto any already-named combinatorial object?

(Note: this is related to a [previous question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/7865/30) of mine about avoiding partial words, but that question only required avoidance east-west, so to speak, whereas here I need to avoid north-south repetitions also.)

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you do not prohibit “a” and “b” appearing in adjacent cells twice as long as the directions are different.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Yes.  "ab" in one place, and "ba" in another is ok, including if they are on the same line, appearing as "aba."

Comment: As a side note, the only relevant reference I have been able to find is [Latin Squares Which Contain no Repeated Digrams](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2027267) from 1965(!).  I am reviewing that now, and it may have useful techniques, but I don't want to limit myself to Latin squares.

Comment: Do you already have some results for small values of $|\Gamma|$? For example, if $|\Gamma| = 3$, what is the largest possible $n$ that can be achieved?

Comment: @Jukka: Considering only the east-west no-repetition requirement, I can show that $|\Gamma| \geq n-2$ through a counting argument. I'm not sure how to approach adding in the north-south restriction also. I haven't worked small examples, but I can do that.

Comment: can the same letter appear next to itself? Like $aa$?

Comment: What if you just take the multiplication table of integers modulo a prime number?

Comment: @Artem yes.  (This is an example of what makes it different from a Latin square.)

Comment: @everyone: thank you all for your rapid interest.  I have to be away from the computer for a while, so I won't be able to comment again for a few hours.  Thanks again.

Comment: A related problem is Seth Pettie's work on forbidden submatrices: http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/papers/FH-J.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDITED TO ADD**:  Gilbert's paper turns out to have historical importance, and it fully solves the problem I asked in my question.  Please see [my blog entry](http://nanoexplanations.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/an-independent-discovery-of-costas-arrays/) for more details.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

It turns out that the paper I found from 1965, Gilbert's [Latin Squares Which Contain No Repeated Digrams](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2027267), is quite helpful.

Using *permutations with distinct differences*, he constructs Latin squares of size $n$ for every even $n$, such that no adjacent pair ever repeats in the square, neither in rows nor columns.  So $|\Gamma| \leq n+1$ in my question, because either the input parameter is even, or I can just add one to it, build the Latin square of size $n+1$, and then chop off one row and one column.

(A permutation with distinct differences is a permutation in which all the differences between consecutive elements are distinct.  So, for example, on three elements, (1 3 2) is a permutation with distinct differences, since $3-1 \neq 2-3$, but (1 2 3) is not, since $2-1 = 3-2$.)

He later generalizes this in a way that relates to Jukka's answer.  Suppose we want not just unique appearances of pairs $ab$, but of $a \lozenge^k b$, where $\lozenge$ is a "don't care" symbol, and $k$ ranges from 0 to $n-2$.  That is to say, for a given $k$, there would be at most one occurrence of $a \lozenge^k b$ in the rows, and at most one in the columns, of the square.  (This is a property that interests me a lot, by the way.)  According to another theorem of Gilbert, it is possible to build a Latin square with such a property if $n+1=p$ where $p$ is prime.

So the question then becomes: given $n$, what is the least prime number larger than $n$?  The Prime Number Theorem, etc., only give asymptotic bounds, but there are some explicit bounds known.  The best one I have found is due to Dusart, [Estimates of Some Functions Over Primes Without RH](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442): for $x \geq 396738$, there is at least one prime in the interval $[x,x+ x/25 \ln^2 x]$.  So, if we want to avoid repetition of pairs with don't-care symbols in between, asymptotically, for large enough $n$, $|\Gamma| \leq n + n/25\ln^2 n$.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Could you perhaps add some examples of the constructions for even $n$?

Comment: @Jukka: Yes.  I might write a blog entry on this.  I will either do that, or add to this answer, or both, over the next couple days.

Answer (score 10):

An extended version of my comment:

Let $p = n+1$ be a prime number. Then we can construct an $n \times n$ square from the multiplication table of integers modulo $p$. For example, if $p = 5$, we have

```
1234
2413
3142
4321
```

Now each pair $ab$ with $a \ne b$ occurs exactly once. Similarly, each pair $a$-above-$b$ with $a \ne b$ occurs exactly once.

Hence this is a valid construction; alphabet size $n$ and an $n \times n$ square.

Moreover, it is optimal. In an $n \times n$ square there are $n(n-1)$ horizontal pairs, and each of them must be different. If we had an alphabet of size $n-1$, we could only construct $(n-1)^2 < n(n-1)$ different horizontal pairs.

Comment: Thanks @Jukka, that's great. It isn't a full answer (as I know you know) because I would like to say something about "all $n$ sufficiently large" not just a set of $n$ with the density of the primes. I will think about extending your approach.